# Is it possible to call both default and parameterized constructors of SubClass and SuperClass for a particular instance(parameterized) in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, parameterized, default-constructor

I'm trying for the below scenario:

```
public class SuperClass {
    public SuperClass(){
        System.out.println("Super Constructor");
    }
    public SuperClass(int i){
        this();
        System.out.println("Parameterized Super Constructor");
    }
}
public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    public SubClass(){
        System.out.println("Sub Constructor");
    }
    public SubClass(int i){
        super(i); /* Need to call **this()** here .. Is this possible? */
        System.out.println("Parameterized  Sub Constructor");
    }
}
public class Inheritance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubClass sub=new SubClass(5);
    }
}
```

How to call both default and parameterized constructors for this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have functionality in the non-parameterized constructor that you need to call for both, then I'd recommend that you just move it out of there into a, for example, `private void init()` function that both constructors can call.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a better idea. But i thought, the calls could be maintained between constructors itself.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, no you cannot call both `this` and `super(i)`. Java only allow you to chain one other constructor in the beginning of a constructor.

You can do what DFreeman suggested or there is another trick in Java;

```
public class SuperClass {
    public SuperClass(){
        System.out.println("Super Constructor");
    }
    public SuperClass(int i){
        this();
        System.out.println("Parameterized Super Constructor");
    }
}
public class SubClass extends SuperClass{

    {
        /*
         * Default initialization block.
         * During compile time, this block will get copy to each of the constructor.
         */
        System.out.println("Sub Constructor");
    }

    public SubClass(int i){
        super(i); 
        System.out.println("Parameterized  Sub Constructor");
    }
}

public class Inheritance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubClass sub=new SubClass(5);
    }
}
```

So if you have some common initialization (like assigning default values), you can take advantage of the default initialization block.

However, if need to call different parameterized constructors in a constructor you are out of luck. You will either have to restructure your constructors or call some common private initialization method.

Comment: Cool.. I'm not aware of this block. Thanks a lot.